# Omniauth (net-ldap requires Ruby version >= 1.8.7.) installation error?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, omniauth

I'm trying crazily to install omniauth on Ubuntu 8.04.4.

I keep getting the following error:

ERROR:  Error installing omniauth:
        net-ldap requires Ruby version >= 1.8.7.

So I updated to Ruby1.9 but still the error persists.  Any idea of why this is happening?
I thought ruby1.8.7 was a minor release, so best practice would suggest moving to Ruby1.9.  Further, and more to the point, I can't find a copy of Ruby1.8.7 anywhere.

EDIT:::::::::::::::

I purged the gems and uninstalled ruby.  Then found a version ruby1.8.7, compiled and installed and now it works great.

Cheers,

Slotishtype.

Comment: Cool!, glad to here it works for you now...

Answer (score 1):

I guess since you have "updated" and not removed the old Ruby version, the gems would be installed to old path where the old Ruby version was installed.

You can verify the same using the command

> gem env

in the terminal. And following the path to where your gems are currently installed.

Also you can check if you have the correct ruby version installed as per your requirement with

> ruby -v

Try removing the old version and then installing a fresh version of Ruby.

You would find Ruby 1.8.7 from http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/.

Good Luck!!

Hope it helps.